# Добавить данные из собственных классов связанных интерфейсом в RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, recyclerview.adapter

У меня есть 3 типа itemsView(экрана) и 3 класса данных для них для RecyclerView. Получение данных идет в ArrayList в каждом классе. Получается классы с списками.
Вот первый класс:

```
public class LoadJustHardPostFromFireBase implements ItemsForPost{
private ArrayList<String> exerciseHard;
private ArrayList<String> otherData;
private int type;

public ArrayList getTrainingEx(DatabaseReference myRef, final FirebaseUser user, int id)
{ получаю данные в список из firebase  return exerciseHard;}

public ArrayList getOtherData(DatabaseReference myRef, final FirebaseUser user, long id)
{получаю вторые данные в список из firebase return otherData;}
```

Второй класс:

```
public class LoadJustCardioPostFromFireBase implements ItemsForPost{
private ArrayList<String> exerciseCard;
private ArrayList<String> otherData;
private int type;

public ArrayList getCardioEx(DatabaseReference myRef, final FirebaseUser user, int id)
{ получаю данные в список из firebase  return exerciseCard;}

public ArrayList getOtherData(DatabaseReference myRef, final FirebaseUser user, long id)
{получаю вторые данные в список из firebase return otherData;}
```

Третий:

```
public class LoadFullGroupPostFromFireBase implements ItemsForPost{
private ArrayList<String> otherData;
private ArrayList<String> exerciseHard;
private ArrayList<String> exerciseCard;
private int type;

public ArrayList getTrainingEx(DatabaseReference myRef, final FirebaseUser user, int id)
{ получаю данные в список из firebase  return exerciseHard;}

public ArrayList getCardioEx(DatabaseReference myRef, final FirebaseUser user, int id)
{ получаю данные в список из firebase  return exerciseCard;}

public ArrayList getOtherData(DatabaseReference myRef, final FirebaseUser user, long id)
{получаю вторые данные в список из firebase return otherData;}
```

Это общий интерфейс для них.

```
public interface ItemsForPost {
    int getItemType ();
}
```

Ну а это адаптер. Инфлейчу ту View к которой подходят данные. В итоге в onBindViewHolder нужно добавлять сами данные согласно типу. (У каждого макета свой класс данных).

```
public class RecyclerAdapterForPost extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapterForPost.myVH3> {
ArrayList<ItemsForPost> items;
private final int TYPE_ITEM_HARD = 1;
private final int TYPE_ITEM_CARDIO = 2;
private final int TYPE_ITEM_GROUP = 0;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
private FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
private DatabaseReference myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(); 

public RecyclerAdapterForPost(ArrayList<ItemsForPost> items){
    this.items = items;
}


@Override
public myVH3 onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v;

    switch (viewType) {
        case TYPE_ITEM_HARD:
            v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.conteiner_post_hard, parent, false);
            break;
        case TYPE_ITEM_CARDIO:
            v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.conteiner_post_cardio, parent, false);
            break;
        default:
            v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.conteiner_post_group, parent, false);
    }
    return new myVH3(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(myVH3 holder, int position) {
    int type = getItemViewType(position);

    switch (type) {
        case TYPE_ITEM_HARD:{

            LoadJustHardPostFromFireBase loadHard = (LoadJustHardPostFromFireBase) items.get(position);

            ArrayList<String> dataOne = loadHard.getTrainingEx(myRef, user, position);
            ArrayList<String> dataThree = loadHard.getOtherData(myRef,user,position);
        }
            break;
        case TYPE_ITEM_CARDIO:{
            LoadJustCardioPostFromFireBase loadCardio = (LoadJustCardioPostFromFireBase) items.get(position);

            ArrayList<String> dataTwo  = loadCardio.getCardioEx(myRef,user,position);
            ArrayList<String> dataThree = loadCardio.getOtherData(myRef,user,position);
        }
            break;
        case TYPE_ITEM_GROUP:{
            LoadFullGroupPostFromFireBase  loadGroup = (LoadFullGroupPostFromFireBase) items.get(position);

            ArrayList<String> dataOne = loadGroup.getTrainingEx(myRef, user, position);
            ArrayList<String> dataTwo = loadGroup.getCardioEx(myRef,user,position);
            ArrayList<String> dataThree = loadGroup.getOtherData(myRef,user,position);
        }
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return items.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    // определяем какой тип в текущей позиции
    int type = items.get(position).getItemType();
    if (type == 1) return TYPE_ITEM_HARD;
    else if (type == 2) return TYPE_ITEM_CARDIO;
    else return TYPE_ITEM_GROUP;

}

public class myVH3 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

     TextView name_person_post;
     TextView data_person_post;
     TextView tonnageNow;
     TextView kpwNow;
     TextView intencityNow;
     TextView timeForTrain;
     TextView exCount;
     TextView myWeightFromProfile;



public myVH3(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    name_person_post= itemView.findViewById(R.id.name_person_post);
    data_person_post= itemView.findViewById(R.id.data_person_post);
    tonnageNow= itemView.findViewById(R.id.tonnageNow);
    kpwNow= itemView.findViewById(R.id.kpwNow);
    intencityNow= itemView.findViewById(R.id.intencityNow);
    timeForTrain= itemView.findViewById(R.id.timeForTrain);
    exCount= itemView.findViewById(R.id.exCCount);
    myWeightFromProfile= itemView.findViewById(R.id.myWeightFromProfile);
}
}
}
```

Я определяю какой мне нужен класс из интерфейса. и пытаюсь получить данные оттуда.

```
 LoadFullGroupPostFromFireBase  loadGroup = (LoadFullGroupPostFromFireBase) items.get(position);

            ArrayList<String> dataOne = loadGroup.getTrainingEx(myRef, user, position);
```

Но вторая строка выдает ошибку.

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference

Если я создаю сначала

```
ArrayList<String> dataOne = new ArrayList(); внутри onBindViewHolder
```

Что будет тоже самое. и если я создаю его глобально в классе Адаптера то тоже самое.

В MainActivity

```
....
private ArrayList<ItemsForPost>   items = new ArrayList<>();
public View onCreateView(...){
items.add(new LoadJustCardioPostFromFireBase(2));
}
....
```

добавление items вот таким кодом. (в зависимости какой нужен тип данных (класса)

Получения данных идет таким методом

```
  public ArrayList<String> getOtherData(DatabaseReference myRef, final FirebaseUser user, int id) {
  final  ArrayList<String> otherData = new ArrayList<>();
 myRef.child(user.getUid()).child("Training").child(String.valueOf(id)).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String kpw;
            String tonnage;
            String intensity;
            String timeTrain;
            String data;
            String myWeight;

            kpw = dataSnapshot.child("Kpw").getValue().toString();
            timeTrain = dataSnapshot.child("TimeTrain").getValue().toString();
            tonnage = dataSnapshot.child("Tonnage").getValue().toString();
            data = dataSnapshot.child("Data").getValue().toString();
            intensity = dataSnapshot.child("Intencity").getValue().toString();
            myWeight = dataSnapshot.child("myWeight").getValue().toString();
            //other

            otherData.add(0,kpw);
            otherData.add(1,tonnage);
            otherData.add(2,intensity);
            otherData.add(3,timeTrain);
            otherData.add(4,myWeight);
            otherData.add(5,data);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) { }
    });
    return otherData;
}
```

Вероятнее всего файлы не успевают догрузиться из FireBase до того как они возвращаются. Как мне поступить в этом случае?

Comment: видимо никакие данные в ваши модели не получено, проверьте, что там вообще есть коллекция

Comment: @pavlofff дописал кусок кода в посте, количество Items (Коллекция интерфейсов) совпадает с количеством виджетов на экране, и если я подставляю данные не из firebase а статически пишу otherData.add("какие то значения") то данные добавляются успешно

Comment: думаю из этого очевидно, что данные из базы не успевает поступить, то есть когда список уже должен отображать данные они еще не получены из БД

Comment: @pavlofff тогда мне нужно добавлять их в onCreate в мейн активити и до того как я присвою адаптер списку. да?

Comment: я сам не работал с firebase, должны быть готовые паттерны вывода данных из этой БД в список. Как самый прямой вариант конечно предварительная подготовка данных перед передачей в список, но возможно есть и более изящные варианты.

Comment: я понял. спасибо большое тебе за все ответы:) к сожалению оценку ставить еще не могу